# How do I calculate the sub total and total in a table in the laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-5.6

If I debug my laravel eloquent, the result like this :

```
SELECT a.transaction_number a.date, a.item_number, b.desc, a.variant_code, sum(a.quantity) AS quantity, a.cost
FROM `items_details` AS a
JOIN `items` AS b ON b.id = a.item_number
WHERE a.item_number = 0101010
GROUP BY a.variant_code
ORDER BY transaction_number, variant_code
```

I will return collection with pagination

But here I just display the array. The array like this :

```
$data = array(
    array('transaction_number' => 'AB-0001','date' => '2018-08-01', 'item_number' => '0101010', 'desc' => 'This is a', 'variant_code' => '002', 'quantity' => '2','cost' => '2000'),
    array('transaction_number' => 'AB-0001','date' => '2018-08-01', 'item_number' => '0101010', 'desc' => 'This is a', 'variant_code' => '004', 'quantity' => '3','cost' => '2000'),
    array('transaction_number' => 'AB-0001','date' => '2018-08-01', 'item_number' => '0101010', 'desc' => 'This is a', 'variant_code' => '005', 'quantity' => '4','cost' => '2000'),
    array('transaction_number' => 'AB-0001','date' => '2018-08-01', 'item_number' => '0101010', 'desc' => 'This is a', 'variant_code' => '006', 'quantity' => '5','cost' => '2000'),
    array('transaction_number' => 'AB-0001','date' => '2018-08-01', 'item_number' => '0101010', 'desc' => 'This is a', 'variant_code' => '008', 'quantity' => '1','cost' => '2000'),
    array('transaction_number' => 'AB-0002','date' => '2018-08-02', 'item_number' => '0101010', 'desc' => 'This is b', 'variant_code' => '013', 'quantity' => '2','cost' => '2000'),
    array('transaction_number' => 'AB-0002','date' => '2018-08-02', 'item_number' => '0101010', 'desc' => 'This is b', 'variant_code' => '020', 'quantity' => '3','cost' => '2500'),
    array('transaction_number' => 'AB-0002','date' => '2018-08-02', 'item_number' => '0101010', 'desc' => 'This is b', 'variant_code' => '022', 'quantity' => '4','cost' => '2500'),
    array('transaction_number' => 'AB-0003','date' => '2018-08-03', 'item_number' => '0101010', 'desc' => 'This is c', 'variant_code' => '007', 'quantity' => '1','cost' => '2500'),
    array('transaction_number' => 'AB-0003','date' => '2018-08-03', 'item_number' => '0101010', 'desc' => 'This is c', 'variant_code' => '015', 'quantity' => '7','cost' => '2500')
);
```

My script in the laravel blade to display it like this :

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>transaction_number</th>
        <th>date</th>
        <th>item_number</th>
        <th>desc</th>
        <th>variant_code</th>
        <th>quantity</th>
        <th>cost</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach ($items as $item)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $item->transaction_number }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item->date }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item->item_number }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item->desc }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item->variant_code }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item->quantity }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item->cost }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

The result like this :

[image]

I want the result like this :

[image]

What is the best way to do it? Whether through mysql query or laravel eloquent to display like that? Or is it arranged through the view blade laravel?

Please, help me. I'm confused :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without pagination, I would do something like this (not tested)...

Requiring pagination adds complexity with regards to potentially breaking up transaction groups and the total.

Have a read of the following,
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#the-loop-variable
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#including-sub-views

You need Laravel 5.3+ for `$loop`.

**subtotal.blade.php**

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="4"></td>
    <td>SUBTOTAL</td>
    <td>{{ $items->where('transaction_number', $current_transaction_number)->sum('quantity') }}</td>
    <td>{{ $items->where('transaction_number', $current_transaction_number)->sum('cost') }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="7"></td>
</tr>
```

**total.blade.php**

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="4"></td>
    <td>TOTAL</td>
    <td>{{ $items->sum('quantity') }}</td>
    <td>{{ $items->sum('cost') }}</td>
</tr>
```

**main.blade.php**

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>transaction_number</th>
        <th>date</th>
        <th>item_number</th>
        <th>desc</th>
        <th>variant_code</th>
        <th>quantity</th>
        <th>cost</th>
    </tr>
    @php ($current_transaction_number = null)

    @foreach ($items as $item)
        @if ($loop->index > 0 && $current_transaction_number != $item->transaction_number)
           @include ('subtotal', compact('items', 'current_transaction_number'))
        @endif
        <tr>
            @if ($current_transaction_number == $item->transaction_number)
                <td colspan="2"></td>
            @else
                @php ($current_transaction_number = $item->transaction_number)
                <td>{{ $item->transaction_number }}</td>
                <td>{{ $item->date }}</td>
            @endif
            <td>{{ $item->item_number }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item->desc }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item->variant_code }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item->quantity }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item->cost }}</td>
        </tr>
        @if ($loop->last)
           @include ('subtotal', compact('items', 'current_transaction_number'))
           @include ('total', compact('items'))
        @endif
    @endforeach
</table>

{{ $items->links() }}
```

Comment: So this doesn't include pagination? Do you have a solution if you use pagination?

Comment: I have updated the code to include pagination links. Note that when paginated, the transaction groups may be split over more than one page. Meaning that the subtotal of the first and last group will not include any lines on other pages. Also, the total will only be for the current page, not all items. It depends on what you require in the subtotal and total rows.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will check again. Btw, for sub total quantity, it's still wrong. It's should be `sum`. Not `count`

Comment: What do you think if this is set in the query sql or laravel eloquent? So pagination can work well

Comment: Have updated the code to output the corrent quantity, also tidied it up by using `Collection` methods to get the subtotals and totals - https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#available-methods

Comment: What do you want the 'sub total' and 'total' rows to reflect? What is on the current page or what is in the database?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177873/discussion-between-steve-and-success-man).

Comment: Okay thanks. I will try it. In the database. No current page

Answer (score 0):

```
@php
    $previous_transaction_number = "";
    $total_quantity = 0;
    $total_cost = 0;
    $subtotal_quantity = 0;
    $subtotal_cost = 0;
@endphp

<table class="table" border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th>transaction_number</th>
        <th>date</th>
        <th>item_number</th>
        <th>desc</th>
        <th>variant_code</th>
        <th>quantity</th>
        <th>cost</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach ($items as $item)
        @if(!empty($previous_transaction_number) && $previous_transaction_number != $item['transaction_number'])
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5" style="text-align:right"><b>SUBTOTAL:</b></td>
                <td><b> {{ $subtotal_quantity }} </b></td>
                <td><b> {{ $subtotal_cost }} </b></td>
            </tr>
            @php
                $subtotal_quantity = 0;
                $subtotal_cost = 0;
                $previous_transaction_number = "";
            @endphp
            <tr>
                <td colspan="7">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        @endif

        <tr>
            @if($previous_transaction_number != $item['transaction_number'])
                <td>{{ $item['transaction_number'] }}</td>
            @else
                <td></td>
            @endif            
            <td>{{ $item['date'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item['item_number'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item['desc'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item['variant_code'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item['quantity'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item['cost'] }}</td>
        </tr>

        @php
            $subtotal_quantity += $item['quantity'];
            $subtotal_cost += $item['cost'];
            $previous_transaction_number = $item['transaction_number'];
            $total_quantity += $item['quantity'];
            $total_cost += $item['cost'];
        @endphp        
    @endforeach
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" style="text-align:right"><b>SUBTOTAL:</b></td>
        <td><b> {{ $subtotal_quantity }} </b></td>
        <td><b> {{ $subtotal_cost }} </b></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="7">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" style="text-align:right"><b>TOTAL:</b></td>
        <td><b> {{ $total_quantity }} </b></td>
        <td><b> {{ $total_cost }} </b></td>
     </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: I had try your code. But it seems it's not perfect. There are items that are sub-total calculations correct. But some are still wrong

Comment: @SuccessMan Can you share the `$data` array for which it went wrong?